# I can't find the Dispathcers.IO in the coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

i'm studying android by a book. according to the book, i need to create a repository to get data from the network response. and i had create a livedata to store info.
here are the codes on my book.

```
object Repository {

    fun searchPlaces(query: String) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result = try {
            val placeResponse = SunnyWeatherNetwork.searchPlaces(query)
            if (placeResponse.status == "ok") {
                val places = placeResponse.places
                Result.success(places)
            } else {
                Result.failure(RuntimeException("response status is ${placeResponse.status}"))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.failure<Place>(e)
        }
        emit(result)
    }
```

But when I copied the codes, i found that the second row's **Dispatchers.IO** was wrong. and i tried to import the **kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers**, the IDE can't find it.
finally i abandoned the codes, and the app run successfully. i can't understand the specific principles

this is my build.gradle.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9"
```

and how can i use the Dispatchers.IO?

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatchers.IO` belongs to `kotlinx-coroutines-core` package.

Add `kotlinx-coroutines-core` implementation to your module's `build.gradle`

```
dependencies{
      def coroutinesVersion = '1.5.2-native-mt'
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion"
}
```

Comment: Is "native-mt" desirable for Android?